# How to presign URL to retrieve image from AWS S3 in react native

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

I'm looking to sign a URL for AWS S3 to Access and display a protected image within my react native app: Thèse all informations i've got :

```
"https://s3.servauto.fr/compression-img/a5d6898a-382c-11ee-bbb5-00155dc60818.webp"

Signature AccessKey: EXAMPLEACCESSKEY

SecretKey:EXAMPLESECRETKEY

AWS Region: eu-west-2 

Service Name: s3,
```

Is there any algorithm, documentation,article or any library to generate presigned URLs in react native ?

I found ressources using that are signing urls for upload but for my case is to Access images. Can i use aws-amplify or aws-sdk to do it ?

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

// Configure AWS credentials
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY',
  secretAccessKey: 'SECRET_KEY',
  region: 'REGION',
});

This is what i've tried so far
// Function to generate a pre-signed URL
export function generateS3PresignedURL(imageUrl, expirationSeconds = 3600) {
  imageUrl =
    'https://s3.bucket-name.com/compression-img/11ee-bbb5-a5d6898a-382c--00155dc60818.webp';
  // Extract bucket and key from the provided URL
  
  const bucket = "s3.bucket-name.com"; // Assuming that 's3.bucket-name.com' is the S3 bucket hostname
  const key = "compression-img/11ee-bbb5-a5d6898a-382c--00155dc60818.webp"; // The rest of the URL is the key

  // Create an S3 object
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();

  // Generate a pre-signed URL
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
    Expires: expirationSeconds,
  };

  return s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
}
```

The result :

```
SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ACCESS_KEYaws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231018T075941Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=SIGNATURE-SignedHeaders=host
```

But it's not working, when i tried to do it i postman and choosed AWS in signature in Authorization, i received another result.
I have also another question, when sending request from postman i'm receiving a blob ? Is it correct ? Is it the same in react native should i receive a blob ?

Comment: Does your mobile app have a backend that users authenticate to?

Comment: Yes WE have a backend that users authenticate to, why ?

Comment: Because your authenticated client app can request an S3 signed URL from your backend.

Comment: The backend is not providing us with a signed url, is it easier and better to do in the backend ?

Comment: Whichever component signs the URL will need AWS credentials (that have the relevant S3 permissions). You generally do not want those credentials on the client. So, you can implement a simple server-side API that returns a pre-signed S3 URL to an authenticated client.

Comment: I need to do it in client side

Comment: Unclear why you need to do it client-side, but if you really do then look at Cognito and Amplify Storage. You should never have your IAM user credentials, or any long-term AWS credentials, on your client.